# aSmack ReconnectionManager problems

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm using aSmack library in my android app for group chatting, my problem is that sometimes when the connection is lost, ReconnectionManager fails to reconnect and gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.startup(PacketWriter.java:119)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:603)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:565)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:991)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager$2.run(ReconnectionManager.java:122)
```

and here's my code:

```
  // Create a connection
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
```

Any Ideas on how to avoid this error? or maybe use a different asmack version, I'm currently using asmack-2010.05.07.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a bug in aSmack, `reconnect()` method in `ReconnectionManager` class must by `synchronized` to avoid this exception, Now I'm using **asmack-android-19-0.8.10.jar** and it has this fix.